# How to run pre-requisites before all suites in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I have NodeJS project with jasmine specs . I want to run pre-requisites before running all specs in the suite for creating pre-requisite test data for the complete suite.

For individual spec , it can be done using beforeAll method, but I want to run pre-requisite script once for one complete test run.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "spec/helpers/myhelper.js" file (See spec/support/jasmine.json for the location of your helpers directory) and put your logic in there. It will be run before the specs execute.